# Start screensaver/ lock screen on screen sharing disconnect

Tags: applescript, script, screen-sharing

Is there a way with an AppleScript or shell script to start the screensaver when you disconnect from a screen sharing session?

For example, I connect via screen sharing from Mac A to Mac B. When I disconnect my remote screen sharing session I would like to start the screen saver on Mac B thus locking that screen.

Comment: You can start a screensaver with `open -a ScreenSaverEngine`, but I don't know how to run it automatically when you disconnect from a screen sharing session.

Answer (score 1):

ScreenSharing will post several distributed notifications during a screen sharing session. It is necessary to listen to those notifications to be able to act on them. I attempted to find a command line executable that is included with Mac OS X to perform this function. Although there is a `notifyutil` executable in Mac OS X, it does not act as an observer to the [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000216-111391). I also looked at the `terminal-notifier` project, but it appears to only post User (GUI) notifications.

I've created a Foundation executable that can be run in the background to detect when a screensharing session ends (and start the ScreenSaverEngine as mentioned by @Lauri Ranta above). I have posted the [source for this executable on GitHub](https://github.com/eddie420/LockOnDisconnect/blob/master/LockOnDisconnect/main.m). You can use Xcode to build the project, and then launch the software as you'd like (via a `launchd` job?)